# Python Click command doesn't recognize options

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-click

I am trying to register command-line options in Click. Everything is working fine until I add the `params` argument to the constructor.

```
class InitCommand(click.Command):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            name='init',
            short_help='Initialize the needed scaffolding.',
            help='something helpful, but longer',
            # params=[]    ### <-- Works fine
            params=[click.Option('--force', default=False)]
        )
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/aquapy", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('aquapy-cli', 'console_scripts', 'aquapy')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 561, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2631, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2291, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2297, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/Users/******/__main__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .bootstrap import main
  File "/Users/******/bootstrap.py", line 17, in <module>
    main.add_command(InitCommand())
  File "/Users/******/commands/init_command.py", line 10, in __init__
    params=[click.Option('--force', default=False)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1460, in __init__
    Parameter.__init__(self, param_decls, type=type, **attrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1266, in __init__
    self._parse_decls(param_decls or (), expose_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1533, in _parse_decls
    raise TypeError('Name defined twice')
TypeError: Name defined twice
```

Comment: You forgot a parenthesis in your `__init__()`. Also, please provide the complete Traceback. Thanks :).

Comment: No, I didn't...??

Comment: How about an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and an explanation of the use case?  The pattern you are using here to init this class looks *nothing* like the way click classes are generally used.

Comment: @VaibhavBajaj The closing `)` is at the bottom. The whole part under `super()` is the arguments to the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `click.Option()` expects the first argument to a list and is not like the decorator version `@click.option()`.

```
params=[click.Option(['--force'], default=False)]
```

Wrapping the command option in a list solved the problem.

Comment: I figured it would behave like the decorator, too, and didn't even think to check the method signature in the Click documentation. Thanks!